Prevent SSRS Execution when No Rows - Across Multiple Data Sets
I occasionally use SSRS to make email exception reports. Because they are exception reports, I only want the email to be sent when there are data rows to report, so the Data Sets are populated with stored procedures which all have a line like IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RAISERROR('No Data',16,1) or similar, which causes the SSRS report to error and not send the email.
However, I have made a report that uses two datasets - how can I do the same thing, but stopping the email only when the total rows across both datasets is zero?
Since the report is being run on a schedule, I know the parameters that will be used to run the report in advance.
I tried putting divide by zero errors and using functions in the report to count the rows of the datasets (the main suggestion I found online), but they do not cause enough of a failure to stop the email. I would like to avoid running the SQL Scripts twice if possible as they are not swift...

Use data driven subscriptions; this is an enterprise feature.

I have access to data-driven subscriptions (although never used one before). Would that force me to run the SQL Scripts twice - once for a row count and once for the data?

I haven't used data driven subscriptions for a long time (only Standard across the business here), so I can't remember how they work under the hood, and/or if that's changed since SQL Server 2008. Though I'm pretty they don't run a row count; the existence of data is what causes the subscription to occur. So if the report runs, and data that meets the requirement of the data driven subscription is returned, the subscription completes. If not, it isn't.

I'll check it out (will have to be tomorrow now). The irony is, it isn't even and end user requirement, but I refuse to be the source of spam!

For the data driven subscription, it can generate a report for each record in the data driven query. No records = No email.

there are a couple of ways to handle this. If you have cascading parameters, then the subscription will fail with invalid parameters - not pretty but works. The second is to declare a variable in your subscription dataset, count the number of records from each datasets, add them up. If total count = o then RAISERROR('No Data',16,1) else run the rest of the subscription code.

@Harry I tried with the cascading parameters and failed, since you can't use aggregates in report parameters... Could you elaborate and I'll give it a go?

@HighPlainsGrifter what I meant was to adjust your data driven subscription query  - this is how I would approach it. If this answers your need, i'll change it to an answer :  https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=dd1e97a6-26f1-400c-b5e1-bc8954e8fe0c

Ah, I see what you mean. I guess maybe I should put my data into a table then - currently it is two SQL Scripts (Stored Procedures) that run when the report is executed. It makes sense that I would have to actualise the data before I can count the rows, whether by running the scripts in a rowcount execution or saving the data to a table... Of the two, I suppose the table is the most efficent and I appreciate your SQL Fiddle demo.
